# Show that $|N_G(\langle x\rangle)|$ is a multiple of $5^2*7$, where $|G|=3*5^2*7$ and $x\in C$, a cyclic subgroup of order 35.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, sylow-theory

### The full question is as follows:

Let $G$ be a group of order $3\cdot5^2\cdot7$.

(a) Let $P$ be a subgroup of $G$ of order $7$. Show that $P$ is normal, or that $G$ contains a cyclic subgroup $C$ of order $35$.

(b) Assuming such a $C$ exists, let $x$ be an element of $C$ of order $5$. Show that the normalizer of $\langle x\rangle$ in $G$ has order equal to a multiple of $5^2\cdot7$.

(c) Explain why the above shows that $G$ is not simple.

### Here's what I have:

(a) By the Sylow counting theorem, the number of Sylow 7-subgroups (denoted $n_7$) is congruent to 1 (mod 7). The possibilities are $n_7=1$ or $n_7=15$. If $n_7=1$, then *the* Sylow 7-subgroup is normal. Otherwise, $n_7=15$ and it follows from the $n!$ theorem that $|n_7|=|G:N_G(S)|$, for some $S\in Syl_7(G)$. By LaGrange's theorem, this gives that the normalizer of $S$ in $G$ is a subgroup of order 35. It remains to be shown that this group is cyclic. This is straightforward application of a theorem that states if $|G|=pq$ for primes $p<q$, and $p\not|(q-1)$, then $G$ is cyclic.

(b) I'm not sure what to do for this. I'd like to use the "normalizers grow theorem", that is, given a finite $p$-group $G$ and proper subgroup $H$, then $H\subsetneq N_G(H)$. However, in this case, $G$ is not a $p$-group. Any advice on how to approach this would be greatly appreciated.

(c) By part (b) and LaGrange's theorem, $|N_G(\langle x\rangle)|=5^2\cdot7$ or $3\cdot5^2\cdot7$. If the latter is true, then $\langle x\rangle$ is normal in $G$ (see https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Normal_Subgroup_iff_Normalizer_is_Group), so $G$ is not simple. If the former is true, then $|[G:N_G(\langle x\rangle)]|=3$. Because $3$ is the smallest prime divisor of $G$, $N_G(\langle x\rangle)$ is normal in $G$, and hence $G$ is not simple.

Comment: Maybe for (c) you can use the following fact: if $[G:H]=p$ where p is the smallest prime that divides the order of $G$, then $H$ is normal.

Comment: For (b) you can prove that $\langle x \rangle$ is normal in the normalizer of $C$.

Comment: @JoseCruz How does proving that $\langle x\rangle$ is normal in the normalizer of $C$ prove that $\langle x\rangle$ is normal in $G$?

Comment: @JoseCruz I edited part (c) to reflect your comment. I believe this is what you were suggesting?

Comment: Yes but what i said  for part (b) is not enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For part (b) you know that $\langle x\rangle$ is normal in $C$, but you also know that there is a $5$-Sylow subgroup Q in which $\langle x\rangle$ is normal. Let's see that $\langle x \rangle$ is normal in the group generated by $C$ and $Q$.
If you take some $c\in C$ and some $t\in Q$, then $ct\langle x\rangle t^{1}c^{-1}=\langle x\rangle$, you can generalize this argument for any element of $\langle C, Q\rangle$.

Since the normalizer of $\langle x\rangle $ is the largest subgroup in which $\langle x\rangle$ is normal, it has to contain $\langle C, Q\rangle$, and this implies, by Lagrange theorem, that $35$ and $5^2$ are divisors of $N_{G}(\langle x\rangle)$.

I hope my answer can help you.

Comment: I'm really sorry, i used the same $P$ you used, i meant that $\langle x\rangle$ is in some 5-sylow, i edited the answer.

Comment: Okay, I agree that $\langle x\rangle$ is normal in $C$. And I agree that such a $Q$ exists and that $\langle x\rangle$ is normal in it. Why does that imply that $\langle x\rangle\triangleleft\langle C,Q\rangle$? And why is the group generated by $C$ and $Q$ equal to the normalizer of $\langle x\rangle$ in $G$?

Comment: I edited the answer, i hope is more helpful.